# Sorting an ArrayList of NotesDocuments using a CustomComparator

Tags: arraylist, xpages

I'm trying to sort a Documents Collection using a java.util.ArrayList.

```
var myarraylist:java.util.ArrayList = new java.util.ArrayList()
var doc:NotesDocument = docs.getFirstDocument();

while (doc != null) {       
    myarraylist.add(doc)                       
    doc = docs.getNextDocument(doc);        
}
```

The reason I'm trying with ArrayList and not with TreeMaps or HashMaps is because the field I need for sorting is not unique; which is a limitation for those two objects (I can't create my own key).

The problem I'm facing is calling CustomComparator:

Here how I'm trying to sort my arraylist:

```
java.util.Collections.sort(myarraylist, new CustomComparator());
```

Here my class:

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import lotus.notes.NotesException;

public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<lotus.notes.Document>{


public int compare(lotus.notes.Document doc1, lotus.notes.Document doc2) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Here");
        System.out.println(doc1.getItemValueString("Form"));             
         return doc1.getItemValueString("Ranking").compareTo(doc2.getItemValueString("Ranking"));
    } catch (NotesException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

}

Error:

> Script interpreter error, line=44, col=23: Error calling method
>   'sort(java.util.ArrayList, com.myjavacode.CustomComparator)' on java
>   class 'java.util.Collections'

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to run your SSJS code in a try-catch block, printing the error in exception in catch block and I got the following message - `java.lang.ClassCastException: lotus.domino.local.Document incompatible with lotus.notes.Document`

I think you have got incorrect fully qualified class names of `Document` and `NotesException`. They should be **`lotus.domino.Document`** and **`lotus.domino.NotesException`** respectively.

Comment: that was the problem; I'm new in Java world and I took lotus.domino.local.Document and lotus.notes.NotesException from Internet.  Here the SSJS from my RepeatControl:    `var docs:NotesDocumentCollection = database.search(query, null, 0);
var myarraylist:java.util.ArrayList = new java.util.ArrayList()
var doc:NotesDocument = docs.getFirstDocument();

while (doc != null) {       
    myarraylist.add(doc)                       
    doc = docs.getNextDocument(doc);        
}

java.util.Collections.sort(myarraylist, new com.mycode.CustomComparator());
return myarraylist;`

Answer (score 1):

Here the SSJS from RepeatControl:

```
var docs:NotesDocumentCollection = database.search(query, null, 0);
var myarraylist:java.util.ArrayList = new java.util.ArrayList()
var doc:NotesDocument = docs.getFirstDocument();

while (doc != null) {       
    myarraylist.add(doc)                       
    doc = docs.getNextDocument(doc);        
}

java.util.Collections.sort(myarraylist, new com.mycode.CustomComparator());
return myarraylist;
```

Here my class:

```
package com.mycode;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<lotus.domino.Document>{


    public int compare(lotus.domino.Document doc1, lotus.domino.Document doc2) {
        try {  
             // Numeric comparison  
             Double num1 = doc1.getItemValueDouble("Ranking");
             Double num2 = doc2.getItemValueDouble("Ranking");         
             return num1.compareTo(num2);
             // String comparison
             // return doc1.getItemValueString("Description").compareTo(doc2.getItemValueString("Description"));
        } catch (lotus.domino.NotesException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not that this answer is necessarily the best practice for you, but the last time I tried to do the same thing, I realized I could instead grab the documents as a NotesViewEntryCollection, via SSJS:

`var col:NotesViewEntryCollection = database.getView("myView").getAllEntriesByKey(mtgUnidVal)`

instead of a NotesDocumentCollection. I just ran through each entry, grabbed the UNIDs for those that met my criteria, added to a java.util.ArrayList(), then sent onward to its destination. I was already sorting the documents for display elsewhere, using a categorized column by parent UNID, so this is probably what I should have done first; still on leading edge of the XPages/Notes learning curve, so every day brings something new.

Again, if your collection is not equatable to a piece of a Notes View, sorry, but for those with an available simple approach, KISS. I remind myself frequently.

Comment: Definitely a valid point. Unfortunately I can't use a View object to get my collection of docs or entries due the complexity of my query string (used on database.search); it has many @Formulas on it. It will be a great addition if XPages team at IBM consider an enhancement like they did on 8.5.3 with FTSearchSorted(), but, for normal NotesDatabase.Search